# Function to re-orient faces in Julia?

Tags: julia, mesh

Tried to find Julia implementation of re-orienting faces of a mesh. Does an implementation exist?

Geometries from external sources not necessary have their faces oriented consistently (even if possible).  If visualized in GLVisualize.jl, coloring vertices of faces not oriented consistently does not come out nicely.

Example Julia code using GLVisualize with a screenshot linked with non-consistent mesh.

```
using GLVisualize, GeometryTypes, GLWindow, GLAbstraction, Colors

vertices = [
 0.0  0.0 0.0
10.0  0.0 0.0
10.0 20.0 0.0
 0.0 20.0 0.0
 0.0  0.0 5.0
10.0  0.0 5.0
10.0 20.0 5.0
 0.0 20.0 5.0
]

faces = [
7 6 5 # 5 6 7 for consistent orientation
5 7 8
1 4 3 
1 3 2
1 2 6
1 6 5
2 3 7
2 7 6
3 4 8
3 8 7
4 1 5
4 5 8
]

v = [ Point{3,Float32}( vertices[i,1:3] ) for i=1:size(vertices,1) ]
f = [ Face{3,UInt32}( faces[i,3:-1:1] ) for i=1:size(faces,1) ]

mesh =  GLNormalAttributeMesh(
            vertices=v, faces=f,
            attributes=RGBA{Float32}[RGBA{Float32}( 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0 )], attribute_id=zeros( length( v ) )
        )

window = glscreen()
_view( visualize( mesh ), window )
renderloop( window )
```

[Brick from the top with non-consistent mesh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9lS1.png)

I could write a slow brute-force algorithm, which would be slow.  Better to ask first.

A recent article suggests the algorithm can be O(N), see https://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.02137.pdf

Note: one should be careful not to look at source implementation of mesh re-orientation in software with non-compatible licenses.

Comment: You might have better success asking at the [discourse message board](https://discourse.julialang.org).  StackOverflow often isn't that great at answering these kinds of questions.

Comment: See: https://discourse.julialang.org/t/function-to-re-orient-mesh-faces/6499